# How to find data of source table from target table in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have two tables, `traders`, and `messages`

Traders is associated to messages as following

```
traders.hasMany(models.messages, {as: 'sender',foreignKey : 'senderId'});
traders.hasMany(models.messages, {as: 'reciever',foreignKey : 'recieverId'});
```

now when I try to find trader name along with all messages using following code

```
   ctx.body = await ctx.db.messages.findAll({
        include:[{
            model: ctx.db.traders,
            as:'sender'
        }],
        attributes:['type',['data','message'],'createdAt','senderId','name'],
        where:{
            conversationId:ctx.request.body.conversationId
        }
    })
```

I get the following error

```
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: traders is not associated to messages!
```

Comment: I want to find name of trader who sent message.

Answer (score 0):

Try association from both models like,

```
traders.hasMany(models.messages, {
    as: 'sender',
    foreignKey: 'senderId'
});

messages.belongsTo(models.traders, {
    as: 'sender',
    foreignKey: 'senderId'
});
```

Comment: this causes cyclic dependency , i have other tables too

Comment: this wont cause cyclic dependency. Try with 'sourceKey' and 'targetKey' http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#one-to-many-associations-hasmany-